# how to write this xpath query?

Tags: xml, xpath, rss

I'm cosuming rss from several sites and my real problem is with their Pubdate field because most of their PubDate values are not valid somehow I manage to retrieve the value from the PubDate fieldset with the help of xpath. this is what I've written :

```
//item/title | 
//item/description | 
//item/link | 
//item/pubDate | 
//item/category
```

and I want to limit my result to 10 latest piece of news I know in xpath we have a function called postion() and I have to use it like following :

```
[postion() <= 10]
```

but when I mix these two xpath queries into together I won't get proper result :

```
 //item/title | 
 //item/description | 
 //item/link | 
 //item/pubDate | 
 //item/category [position() <= 10]
```

how can I write this particular xpath query in correct format.
and is there any fast-track book for xpath around?

regads.

Comment: ">is there any fast-track book". You seem to be in a hurry - you don't even take the time to write sentences with full stops and capital letters, or to spell "position" correctly. Relax, pause for breath, stop to think: study the technologies you are using properly, acquire some expertise and experience, and in the long run it will save you lots of time.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete one-liner XPath expression and an extensive explanation. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the latest news are at the top.

**Use**:

```
(//item)[not(position() > 10)]/*
           [self::title or self::description 
           or self::link or self::pubDate or self::category
           ]
```

**Explanation**:

This expression selects all `title`, `description`, `link`, `pubDate` and `category` elements that are children of one of the first 10 `item` elements in the XML document.

It is a FAQ and an often commited mistake to try selecting the first (or any position element, say `item`) by:

```
//item[1]
```

This selects all `item` elements in the document that are the first child of their parent -- and there may be many such `item` elements.

The XPath expression that selects just the first `item` element in the document is:

```
(//item)[1]
```

**Rule to remember**: The `[]` operator has higher precedence (binds stronger) than the `//` abbreviation.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to limit my result to 10 latest
>   piece of news

```
/descendant::item[
   10 > last()-position()
]/*[
   self::title|self::description|self::link|self::pubDate|self::category  
]
```

Comment: +1 for another correct approach. But I don't really like `10 > last()-position()`. I stumbled upon it a little, less understandable imho.

Comment: @Flack: I agree with you. It might be less understandable the first time. But I prefer this form because in XSLT you don't need to escape `>` "greater than" character with the `&gt;` entity, making the expression more readable.

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
//item[position() <= 10]/pubDate
```

as you want the 10th item!

Comment: this what I've written : //item[position() <= 10]/title | //item[position() <= 10]/description | //item[position() <= 10]/link | //item[position() <= 10]/pubDate | //item[position() <= 10]/category   but "category" field gonna be empty after executing this query